Is there a repository for PSML pseudopotentials files?
I am looking for repositories with tested pseudopotentials in PSML format to be used with SIESTA software.
At least in my notebook, the Pseudo-Dojo that claim to support pseudopotentials for different theories and in different formats is only showing pseudopotentials for PBE and in psp8 format.
I accessed the site with three different browsers (Brave/Chrome/Opera) with the same result.

Actually, Pseudo-Dojo have pseudopotentials for different theories and in different formats but the background and text color choice is bad for their webpage. So it appears white and is misleading. You are probably now seeing this only PBE and psp8:

You can use the dropdown menus to expand them and you can find the desired psml like below.

I changed some HTML coloring locally to show all the possibilities below:

So, I don't think it's a browser problem but just FYI, I am using Chrome browser.

Thank you very much! Shame on me! LOL

It may be a browser issue, I only tried one version of Firefox and one version of Chromium, but Firefox displayed it correctly and Chromium incorrectly.

@jme52 I do not think it's a browser issue. I tried it from Firefox 117, Windows 11 and both the fontcolor and the background-color are still white. However, Firefox has a slightly darker overlay for which the text is a little visible.
